# Plotting function with different values using different colors and line thickness

Tags: plot-themes

In this exercise we will explore a simple application of the Plot[..] function. Consider four functions: 
sin(x), sin(x+[Pi]/5), sin(x+(2[Pi])/5), sin(x+(3[Pi])/5) defined on the interval [0,6[Pi]].

1. Plot these functions together in the same plot, using the options PlotTheme[RightArrow]"Business", PlotLegends[RightArrow]"Expressions", and PlotLabel->"Graph of the sin(x) function and its translates"
2. Do a second plot of these functions, but this time choose your own styling options so that the even translations sin(x+k[Pi]/5), k=0,2 are plotted in Black color, Thick lines, whereas the odd translations k=1,3 are plotted in Blue color, and Dashed lines. Include some appropriate PlotLegends as well

Comment: So you basically want someone to do your work for you without any effort of your own ... http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html

Comment: No, I wanted someone to explain the functions needed to generally plot values of a function with different thicknesses...but thanks for the comment, A+ for passive aggressiveness

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[Sin[x + n*Pi/5], {n, 0, 3}],
 {x, 0, 6 Pi},
 PlotTheme -> "Business",
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Graph of the " <>
   ToString[Sin[x], TraditionalForm] <> 
   " function and its translates"]
```

[image]

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[Sin[x + n*Pi/5], {n, 0, 3}],
 {x, 0, 6 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Blue, Dashed}},
 PlotTheme -> "Business",
 PlotLegends -> Table[Sin[x + n*Pi/5], {n, 0, 3}],
 PlotLabel -> "Graph of the sin(x) function and its translates"]
```

[image]